# App crashes when changing fragment before it created

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I have 2 fragments on main activity , and replace between them with 2 buttons. 
1st button - Lights fragment.
2nd button - Garage fragment.
Lights fragment - a main fragment that created when app opens.
This fragment contain RecyclerView with image that loaded from firebase with Glide.

The problem is, that when the app opens, if the image on LightsFragment still not loaded , and i change to 2nd fragment (GarageFragment) , so when i back to the LightsFragment , app crashes - see logs below the code.

LightsAdapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LightsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LightsAdapter.LightsViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Light> lights;
    private OnLightImageTouchListener onLightImageTouchListener;
    private int selected = -1;
    private Light light;

    public LightsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Light> lights) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lights = lights;
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<Light> lights) {
        this.lights = lights;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public interface OnLightImageTouchListener {
        void onLightImageTouch(int position, MotionEvent motionEvent, LightsViewHolder holder);
    }

    public void setOnLightImageTouchListener(OnLightImageTouchListener onLightImageTouchListener) {
        this.onLightImageTouchListener = onLightImageTouchListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public LightsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lights_item, parent, false);
        return new LightsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final LightsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        light = lights.get(position);
        holder.rootItemView.setTag(position);

        **//Glide - image loader.
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(light.getLampImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .override(200, 200)
                .into(holder.IVLightImage);**


        setLightColor(holder, position);

        //This method called from LightsFragment.
        holder.rootItemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                int position = (int) view.getTag();
                selected = position;
                if (onLightImageTouchListener != null) {
                    onLightImageTouchListener.onLightImageTouch(position, motionEvent, holder);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lights.size();
    }

    public class LightsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView IVLightImage;
        private CardView rootItemView;


        public LightsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            IVLightImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lightImage);
            rootItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootItemView);
        }
    }

    //Open light information on bottom sheet dialog.
    public void openLightInfo(int position) {
        View modelBottomSheet = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lights_info_bottom_sheet, null);
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(modelBottomSheet);
        TextView TVlightTitle = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lightTitle);
        TextView TVLightDesc = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lightDesc);
        TextView TVLightType = dialog.findViewById(R.id.lightType);
        TVlightTitle.setText(lights.get(position).getLampTitle());
        TVLightDesc.setText(lights.get(position).getLampDesc());
        TVLightType.setText(String.valueOf(lights.get(position).getLampType()));
        dialog.show();
    }

    //Set light color according to warning priority (1-4)
    public void setLightColor(LightsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (lights.get(position).getLampType()) {
            case 1:
                holder.IVLightImage.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.IVLightImage.setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
            case 3:
                holder.IVLightImage.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case 4:
                holder.IVLightImage.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

LightsView - dataLoader:

```
public class LightsView {

    private ArrayList<Light> lights = new ArrayList<>();
    private Light light;
    private FirebaseDatabase db;
    private DatabaseReference allLights;
    private LightsPresenter lightsPresenter;

    public LightsView(ArrayList<Light> lights, Light light, LightsPresenter lightsPresenter) {
        this.lights = lights;
        this.light = light;
        this.lightsPresenter = lightsPresenter;
    }

    public void loadData() {
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        allLights = db.getReference("AllLights");
        allLights.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    light = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Light.class);
                    lights.add(light);
                    Log.i("LightsDataLoaded", "true " + light.getLampTitle());
                }
                lightsPresenter.setAdapter();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("LightsDataLoaded", "false ");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

MainActivity - onCreate method that create LightsFragment:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();
        initFunctions();
    }

    public void initFunctions() {
        showLightsFragment();
        showGreetings();
    }

    **public void showLightsFragment() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, this.lightsFragment)
                .commit();
    }**
```

LightsModel:

```
public class Light implements Comparable<Light> {

    private int lampType;
    private String lampTitle;
    private String lampDesc;
    private String lampImageUrl;

    public Light() {
    }

    public Light(int lampType, String lampTitle, String lampDesc, String lampImageUrl) {
        this.lampType = lampType;
        this.lampTitle = lampTitle;
        this.lampDesc = lampDesc;
        this.lampImageUrl = lampImageUrl;
    }

    public int getLampType() {
        return lampType;
    }

    public void setLampType(int lampType) {
        this.lampType = lampType;
    }

    public String getLampTitle() {
        return lampTitle;
    }

    public void setLampTitle(String lampTitle) {
        this.lampTitle = lampTitle;
    }

    public String getLampDesc() {
        return lampDesc;
    }

    public void setLampDesc(String lampDesc) {
        this.lampDesc = lampDesc;
    }

    public String getLampImageUrl() {
        return lampImageUrl;
    }

    public void setLampImageUrl(String lampImageUrl) {
        this.lampImageUrl = lampImageUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Light o) {
        return Integer.compare(lampType, o.lampType);
    }
}
```

LightsFragment:

```
public class LightsFragment extends Fragment implements LightsPresenter {

    private RecyclerView RVLights;
    private ArrayList<Light> lights = new ArrayList<>();
    private Light light;
    private LightsAdapter lightsAdapter;
    private LightsView presenter;
    private View view;
    private Animation animation;

    public LightsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lights, container, false);
            initView(view);
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                presenter = new LightsView(lights, light, this);
                presenter.loadData();
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    //Setting adapter parameters.
    @Override
    public void setAdapter() {
        lightsAdapter = new LightsAdapter(getActivity(), lights);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        RVLights.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RVLights.setAdapter(lightsAdapter);
        lightsAdapter.setOnLightImageTouchListener(new LightsAdapter.OnLightImageTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLightImageTouch(final int position, MotionEvent event, LightsAdapter.LightsViewHolder holder) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in);
                        holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
                        Log.d("IsTouched", "positionTouchedDown " + position);
                        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                        mainActivity.removeSortFragment();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                lightsAdapter.openLightInfo(position);
                                lightsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }, 100);
                        Log.d("IsTouched", "positionTouchedUP" + position);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Sorting adapter by warning color ( 1-4, red - blue )
    public void sortAdapter() {
        Collections.sort(lights);
        lightsAdapter.updateData(lights);
    }

    //Initializing views.
    public void initView(View view) {
        RVLights = view.findViewById(R.id.RVLights);
    }
}
```

Logs from logcat:

```
2019-11-12 15:51:57.939 6889-6889/com.enjoyapp.carhelper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.enjoyapp.carhelper, PID: 6889
    java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:31)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:684)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:716)
        at com.enjoyapp.carhelper.Adapters.LightsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(LightsAdapter.java:67)
        at com.enjoyapp.carhelper.Adapters.LightsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(LightsAdapter.java:26)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:557)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
```

Comment: show us your error log!

Comment: When your app crashes, see the stacktrace in the Logcat window to understand what has happened

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add logs.. Added to post question. Please see

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the method "onViewCreated" inside the LightsFragment and inside that method call

```
initView(view);
```

Then override the method "onAttach" and write inside it

```
presenter = new LightsView(lights, light, this);
presenter.loadData();
```

Pay attention because the fragment is the view not the presenter. In this case the presenter is your LightsView. The presenter take all the logic of your view while the view show what the presenter tells it to do. So, you have to implement "LightsPresenter" in LightsView.

Comment: Hi @Caffo17,
I'm make it now, but now i have a new problem hhh,
After i change fragment and going back to lights fragment , the data duplicated.